# Embedding resource in DNN module gives 404

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, webresource.axd

I'm trying to embed a javascript file in a DNN module, the script tag is created but the content is a 404 error.

The namespace of my project is "Carroussel" the location of my file is "js/jquery-carouFredSel-6.2.1.js"

I've added the following code to AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: WebResource("Carroussel.js.jquery-carouFredSel-6.2.1.js", "application/javascript", PerformSubstitution = true)]
```

And the following to the OnInit of the module:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptResource(GetType(), "Carroussel.js.jquery-carouFredSel-6.2.1.js");
}
```

The scripttag is created in my html:

```
<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=gnpD_kHZKrDN3DKUCn2faE-x6tdus2cDJ1HjymfAToCQgqX2ggJno51OH2VqPx8ArZPoUm5RuWxhg8uAOTZaysKJE7jz3kpB6gHWbD25o2plphslAJao3Rs5ybJz_M9vLB1NmgPujgOBCt3pDGs9aY_lTy04oPXMqX6dyz0AHhjrbZlKl8muO0ZRGnAiWwdicmeAlg2&amp;t=635349640675857733" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But as soon as I view the source i get:

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /WebResource.axd
```

Any ideas on what to change to make this working?

Comment: Don't you need to "path" the JS, like /js/Carroussel.js?

Comment: If I'm correct, the correct format is {namespace}.{directory}.{filename}, so directory seperators are replaced with a dot

Comment: Apparently it must also be referenced in your web.config.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/a/526007/1662973

Comment: Yes, I already tried that and unfortunately didnt make any difference. Also I added WebResource.axd to web.config, didnt make any difference either

Comment: @Mark searching for a similar solution to be able to embed javascripts and css files into my assembly. I know this question is to old but I'd like to know if you had found a solution ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you not embed it, but let DNN handle the registration/loading of the resource. Doing so will allow you to easily see references to the JS if you have CDF disabled in DNN, and mask the references and have the content minified with CDF enabled in DNN.

Here is how to reference the client resource manager in DNN.

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
      DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestUIRegistration();
      ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(Parent.Page, "~/Resources/Shared/scripts/knockout.js");
      ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(Parent.Page, "~/desktopmodules/DnnChat/scripts/moment.min.js");
      ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(Parent.Page, "~/desktopmodules/DnnChat/scripts/DnnChat.js",150);
      base.OnInit(e);
}
```

pulled from https://github.com/ChrisHammond/dnnCHAT/blob/master/View.ascx.cs

Comment: While waiting on the answer on this question, I had already implemented this with a similar approach. Works great and I think I'm going to use it in the module. The RequestUIRegistration is great btw, didn't know this functionality before. Thanks!